# How can i get all orders in Magento with REST?

Tags: rest, magento

I want to get all orders in Magento with REST, and I am getting back a bad request every time.

Here is the endpoint what I am hitting:

```
Magento_host + /rest/V1/orders/searchCriteria=all
```

The Authorization, and Content-type header is set up good, and with a little change i can get products, and customers, but for some reason for Orders it is not working.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with this:

Magento_host + `/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria=''`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.

```
Magento_host + /rest/V1/orders/searchCriteria=0
```

Comment: Still no result :(